# Laravel - Trying to get property "id" of non-object

Tags: laravel, api

I am writing an endpoint with Laravel. When I tested on Postman, I got this error:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property 'id' of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\testing-file\testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\DelegatesToResource.php on line 120

Controller

```php
public function showBilling($id)
{
     return new BillingResource($id);       
}
```

Model

```php
class Billing extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'billing';

    protected $fillable = [
        'network' ,
        'sender',
        'recipient',
        'message',
        'timestamp',
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'amount',
        'billing_type',
        'user_id',
        'service_name',
        'package',
        'email',
        'user_id'
    ];    


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

}
```

Resource

```php
namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;
use App\Billing;

class BillingResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'network' => $this->network,
            'sender' => $this->sender,
            'recipient' => $this->recipient,
            'message' => $this->message,
            'amount' => $this->amount,
            'billing_type' => $this->billing_type,
            'email' => $this->email,
            'user' => $this->user,
            'service' => $this->service,
            'package' => $this->package,
            // Casting objects to string, to avoid receive create_at and update_at as object
            'timestamp' => (string) $this->timestamp,          
            'created_at' => (string) $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => (string) $this->updated_at
          ];
    }
}
```

If I use this GET Request:

> http://localhost/testing-file/testing/api/showBilling/56

It is supposed to show the row affected, but I get this error:

> ErrorException: Trying to get property "id" of non-object in file C:\xampp\htdocs\testing-file\testing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Http\Resources\DelegatesToResource.php on line 120

Comment: what is your `$id` argument? The number 56 or the User model with the id of 56. The resource needs a model in order to work it does not do the query by itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Mofolumike and welcome to StackOverflow!
As far as I can see, the problem is in wrong route model binding. All you need to change is:

```php
public function showBilling(Billing $billing)
{
     return new BillingResource($billing);       
}
```

Also, you need to be sure that the route has valid parameter name. For instance (routes/api.php):

```php
Route::get('some/path/{billing}', 'BillingController@showBilling');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the model to the resource, instead of just the id:

```php
public function showBilling($id)
{
     return new BillingResource(Billing::find($id));       
}
```

You can also use route model binding, as suggested by Andrew G.

Answer (score 1):

Try to give the model to the resource, instead of just the id:

```php
public function show($id)
{
     return BillingResource::make(Billing::find($id));       
}
```

```php
public function show(Billing $billing)
{
     return BillingResource::make($billing);       
}
```

this is your route:

```
Route::get('/billings/{billing}','BillingController@show');
```